# How could I pass multiple collections to View as parameter from Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to send a collection of data to a View from a Controller. I managed to make my code work with a single collection. Is it possible to achieve this with multiple collections (not using ViewBag but rather passing these as parameters to the View)?

What I tried:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> DictOne = MyObjOne.DictOne;
    Dictionary<int, string> DictTwo= MyObjTwo.DictTwo;
    return View(new { DictOne, DictTwo });
}
```

What I have (working already):

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> DictOne = MyObjOne.DictOne;
    return View(DictOne);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Dictionary<int, string>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>&nbsp;
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Test
                            </th>                                
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @kvp.Value
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I change the controller and view to pass these dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create new class (eg. `ViewModel`)
2. Add DictOne and DictTwo as properties
3. Fill `ViewModel` with your dictionaries
4. Pass `ViewModel` to view

Example:

```
public class ViewModel{
    public Dictionary DictOne {get;set;}
    public Dictionary DictTwo {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> DictOne = MyObjOne.DictOne;
    Dictionary<int, string> DictTwo= MyObjTwo.DictTwo;

    ViewModel model = new ViewModel(){
    DictOne = DictOne,
    DictTwo = DictTwo
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model ViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>&nbsp;
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Test
                            </th>                                
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in Model.DictOne)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @kvp.Value
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                        @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in Model.DictTwo)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @kvp.Value
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the multiple dictionaries in a DataClass wrapper.Then in you View you can specify the class as

```
View
@model Namespace.ClassName

Model
    Class YourDataClass
    {
       Dictionary 1;
       Dictionary 2;
    }

Controller 
Return View(object);
```

Comment: How could I define what dictionary to loop through in the View then? Calling it by `Namespace.ClassName.DictionaryName`?

Comment: @Barrosy Please, take a look at my answer an see if it helps.

Comment: @barrosy your model will be the complete object .Model.DictionaryObject name will be the dictionary.To loop through it you have to use for each loop.